Cleanest way to make a git repo out of a local directory and use it to initialize a remote repo on github
I have a fairly common workflow where I have a local directory with some work, and I want to create a local repo and a remote repo with it. The flow I have seems rather clumsy, any advice much appreciated:

Create remote repo manually on github.com.
git init in local directory.
git remote add origin https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
git pull  --allow-unrelated-histories
git push

My specific question is: does a command exist that takes a local repo and automatically creates a remote repo in my account on github? If not that, how do I avoid the git pull  --allow-unrelated-histories which is clearly frowned upon.

When creating the repo manually, don’t tell it to initialize with a README and you can skip pulling. Also, git push -u origin HEAD will set the upstream and push to a remote branch with the same name at the same time.

Use the gh command line tool to create the remote repo without using the web interface, ie all the work happens at the command line.
